# Java. Comparator

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, изучаю книгу Head First Java и дошел до примера с использованием компаратора в коллекциях. Пример из книги:

```
package Jukebox3;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Song  {
    String title;
    String artist;
    String rating;
    String bpm;

    public int compareTo(Song s) {
        return title.compareTo(s.getTitle());
    }

    Song(String t, String a, String r, String b) {
        title = t;
        artist = a;
        rating = r;
        bpm = b;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public String getBpm() {
        return bpm;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
}

public class Jukebox3 {

    ArrayList<Song> songList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Jukebox3().go();

    }

    class ArtistCompare implements Comparator<Song> {
        public int compare(Song one, Song two) {
            return one.getArtist().compareTo(two.getArtist());
        }
    }

    public void go() {
        getSongs();
        ArtistCompare artistCompare = new ArtistCompare();
        Collections.sort(songList, artistCompare);
        System.out.println(songList);
    }

    void getSongs() {
        try  {
            File file = new File("SongList.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                addSong(line);
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void addSong(String lineToParse) {
        String[] tokens = lineToParse.split("/");   
        Song nextSong = new Song(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3]);
        songList.add(nextSong);
    }
}
```

Как работает этот метод:

```
void addSong(String lineToParse) {
        String[] tokens = lineToParse.split("/");   
        Song nextSong = new Song(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3]);
        songList.add(nextSong);
    }
```

У нас в файле 5 строк, эти пять строк мы разбиваем на 4 части и добавляем в массив. Далее создаем новый объект `Song` и добавляем его в коллекцию `ArrayList<Song>`. И т.к. строк в файле 5, то и объектов в коллекции будет соответственно тоже 5. Правильно ли я понял в этом месте?

Далее идет компаратор:

```
class ArtistCompare implements Comparator<Song> {
        public int compare(Song one, Song two) {
            return one.getArtist().compareTo(two.getArtist());
        }
    }
```

Он сравнивает 2 объекта, но объектов у нас 5, как он сравнит остальные?
Помогите пожалуйста, совсем туго доходит :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компараторы используются для сортировки объектов в коллекции. Задача компаратора - сравнить два элемента и сказать, какой из них имеет приоритет над другим (говоря формальным языком, установить отношение *порядка* между ними). Алгоритм сортировки на шаге сортировки применяет компаратор к двум значениям и решает, в каком порядке поместить их в коллекцию.

Например, для чисел таким приоритетом является само значение числа: при сортировке по возрастанию среди любых двух чисел меньшее будет ближе к началу коллекции, большее - ближе к концу.

Компаратор `ArtistCompare` из вашего примера сравнивает две песни по значениям строкового поля `artist`. Таким образом песни при использовании этого компаратора будут отсортированы лексикографически по именам исполнителей.